# When compiling sCrypt-based cryptocurrency QT client, common error thrown

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography, qmake, mingw32

I'm working on my coin at the moment, following the guide posted here:
http://devtome.com/doku.php?id=scrypt_altcoin_cloning_guide

I've used the same libraries, installed them correctly -- everything! However, I get the following error during compilation.

Commands used are:

qmake "USE_UPNP=-" syncoin-qt.pro

make -f Makefile.Release

```
c:\deps\boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp: At global scope:
c:\deps\boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222:36: warning: 'boost::system::posix
_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
c:\deps\boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223:36: warning: 'boost::system::errno
_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
c:\deps\boost/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224:36: warning: 'boost::system::nativ
e_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
mingw32-make: *** [build/bitcoin.o] Error 1
```

After reading on bitcoin forums, I found a post by shakezula that mentioned this was frequently a result of missing "__NO_SYSTEM_INCLUDES". However, that is included in my .pro file, which you can find here:

http://pastebin.com/4p4BMPAE

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by downloading the CoinLab build environment; for those interested, the QT version was 4.8.4, with MinGW as the version bundled with GCC 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm right where you are when you posted this atm.  Kinda stuck here as well...  Are you using Qt 5.2?  I think we may need to use 4.8.5 to get anything done.